# Book where humans on another planets are cannibals

Tags: story-identification

Trying to remember the name/author of a book:

- Long book. Many many separate small chapters.
- Scifi about humans, on non-Earth planet. They have poisonous native life, and can only eat a few brought from Earth plants.
- Because of that, they practice cannibalism, to no waste human body proteins. The story opened with consuming a body of someone who recently died.
- It had a pretty complex plot, with politics, war, technology, social structures, etc.
- Social/sexual customs were kind of weird even leaving aside rituals around cannibalism. But it was NOT Heinlein, I'm sure of that :)

I don't know the year it was published, but it was pretty old, I took it around 1993-95 from a library and the physical book looked well-read by that time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is "[Courtship Rite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtship_Rite)" by Donald Kingsbury.

I've not read it personally, but the plotline described on Wikipedia seems a solid fit.

> Geta is a harsh planet settled by humanity centuries before the novel
>   begins.
>
> Geta is much drier than Earth. Terraforming was never, or very
>   minimally, initiated on the planet's biosphere, leaving it very
>   inhospitable to the descendants of the original settlers, who have
>   become mythic, God-like creatures to its denizens.
>
> Apparently the only Earth-life on Geta are humans, bees, and the
>   "Eight Sacred Plants", including wheat, soybeans, barley, and
>   potatoes. Native, "profane" life includes plants, a wide variety of
>   sea-creatures and "insects", but no large land-animals. Each has a
>   different biochemistry, so each is largely toxic to the other. As a
>   result, food is a commodity that is very precious on Geta, and in most
>   places the only source of meat is humans themselves. Cannibalism has
>   insinuated itself into the very fabric of social and religious life.

It's also described elsewhere as being epic in length with lots of short chapters.

[image: Courtship Rite]

Comment: "Eight Sacred Plants" rings a very big bell. I'll check more details but this sounds like it may be it.

Comment: @DVK - For the record, this book looks awful...

Comment: @Richard it was fairly well liked when it came out - a Hugo nominee.  I never managed to get past the first few dozen pages though.

Comment: I read it many years ago. I found it interesting and fairly entertaining, though not wonderful.