# Helicopter gun god?

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a science fiction novel in which "the only food of man is man".  This was because humans had settled a planet on which there was no compatible life to eat. It also featured the phrase "helicopter gun God", because the word for God was ship. Can anyone tell me the name of this novel?

Answer (score 13):

Could you be thinking of *[Courtship Rite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtship_Rite)* by Donald Kingsbury, first serialized in Analog magazine in 1982?

> Apparently the only Earth-life on Geta are humans, bees, and the "Eight Sacred Plants", including wheat, soybeans, barley, and potatoes. Native, "profane" life includes plants, a wide variety of sea-creatures and "insects", but no large land-animals. Each has a different biochemistry, so each is largely toxic to the other. Parts of certain profane species can be eaten if prepared correctly. As a result, food is a commodity that is very precious on Geta, and in most places the only source of meat is humans themselves. Cannibalism has insinuated itself into the very fabric of social and religious life. On the other hand, humans are not at risk of infection from native bacteria, and seem not to have brought any pathogens with them.
>
> The planet seems to have been settled centuries before the time of the story by a small group, possibly not by choice. Apparently, they made little use of printed materials that could be read in a world without advanced technology. Most knowledge of history and the larger universe was therefore lost, the remainder preserved by oral tradition in "Chants" and stories. The settlers' ship remains in orbit, but its nature has been forgotten; it is generally referred to as "God". The Horse survives only as a piece in chess, named for a "mythical sidestepping insect".

The story features the following passage

> *“We’ve puzzled it out. This is what it says.” She wrote for them:
>
> SOMBER **HELICOPTER GUNGOD** FLEW BEYOND THE RANGE OF*

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing in a book quote.

Comment: If it is the correct answer, it's a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50587/book-where-humans-on-another-planets-are-cannibals. But if it is, Dr. Mouse, you can still accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: The OP [has confirmed this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174982/33591) in a self-answer to a repost of this question under a different account.